# How can I create panelAccordion in ORACLE MAF?

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

panelAccordion component was supported in ADF Mobile but not in ORACLE MAF. Is it possible to achieve this feature in MAF?

Answer (score 2):

Accordion are not common in mobile apps since they consume too much space for the areas they don't show- you usually use a different approach to showing different data on the same area - in MAF you can use the card component to achieve this.

Use a toolbar to control what card is being shown.